# Is there any way to print a Trello board so that it prints the way it looks on the screen?

Tags: trello

I want to print Trello boards but want them to look exactly as they do on the web interface. Trello seems to take all styles away, and print it as a black and white list. Is there any way to have it not do that?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Chrome, you might want to use the [Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) app. You can then just set the browser to full screen mode, load your Trello boards and activate the app. It outputs a nice PNG that you can then print. Hope that helps.

Comment: I also recommend Awesome Screenshot. http://awesomescreenshot.com/